# how to get USB hardware id using device id?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, usb

How to get hardware id of the usb device using device id...i am using vc++6.0 and OS is xp.
is it possible by using wmi.

Comment: Can you post some detail of what you have already?

Comment: Note that a device ID itself already _IS_ a hardware ID. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567931.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Finally i solved my problem...thanks for your replies...
I am posting the code here, it may be useful for someone... by this code we can get all hardwareids of the devices which are connceted to our system..

```
HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
   SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
   DWORD i;

   // Create a HDEVINFO with all present devices.
   hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL,
       0, // Enumerator
       0,
       DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES );

   if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
       //Error handling here.
       printf("Error Details:[%s]\n","INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE");
       return 1;
   }

   // Enumerate through all devices in Set.

   DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
   for (i=0;SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo,i,
       &DeviceInfoData);i++)
   {
       DWORD DataT;
       LPTSTR buffer = NULL;
       LPTSTR hwbuffer=NULL;
       DWORD buffersize = 0;

       //
       // Call function with null to begin with, 
       // then use the returned buffer size (doubled)
       // to Alloc the buffer. Keep calling until
       // success or an unknown failure.
       //
       //  Double the returned buffersize to correct
       //  for underlying legacy CM functions that 
       //  return an incorrect buffersize value on 
       //  DBCS/MBCS systems.
       // 
       while (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
           hDevInfo,
           &DeviceInfoData,
           SPDRP_HARDWAREID,
           &DataT,
           (PBYTE)buffer,
           buffersize,
           &buffersize))
       {

           if (GetLastError() == 
               ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
           {
               // Change the buffer size.
               if (buffer) LocalFree(buffer);
               // Double the size to avoid problems on 
               // W2k MBCS systems per KB 888609. 
              buffer = (char*)LocalAlloc(LPTR,buffersize * 2);
           }
           else
           {
               //Error handling here.
               //printf("Error Details:[%s]\n",GetLastError());
               break;
           }
       }
        printf("Test Result:[%s]\n",buffer);



       if (buffer) LocalFree(buffer);
   }


   if ( GetLastError()!=NO_ERROR &&
        GetLastError()!=ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS )
   {
       // Error handling here.
       printf("Error Details:[%s]\n",GetLastError());
       return 1;
   }

   //  Cleanup
   SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);


   return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be somewhat confused because you assume *the* hardware ID. `IoGetDeviceProperty(yourDevice, DevicePropertyHardwareID, ...)` returns a list.

Comment: Isn't this a kernel level function? Can we call this function from user mode? I think functions that start with Io and return NTSTATUS are meant for drivers only...